# Passing array of strings to Java REST API using axios doesn't work

Tags: java, jersey, axios

I am trying to send an array of strings using axios to a rest endpoint using jersey with spring boot and tomcat. It results in a 404 and I am clueless. The url being passed is correct because if I send a single string with GET it works correctly.

EDIT: Any exception within any another endpoint (say NullPointerException) also results in 404 being shown in the browser. This is something to do with the configuration. So 404 is kind of a red herring status code.

This is my java side code

```
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import javax.ws.rs.*;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import java.util.*;

    @Component
    @Path("v1/")
    public class SomeResourceV1 {
        @POST
        @Path("delete")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public void deleteFoo(List<String> ids) {
            if (ids != null) {
                  // do something
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the typescript code:

```
public delete(someIds : string[]) {
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "/v1/delete",
        data: someIds
    }).then((response : any) => {

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("*** delete error ***", error);
    });
}
```

I have also tried to send data as

```
data:{
  ids: someIds
}
```

I have also attempted to use transformRequest but to no avail. 
How does I fix this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try with @Path("/delete) What is the path that you have on your class?

Comment: Can you post the whole endpoint code as well?